# Why is Entity Framework ignoring the Take() method when generating SQL?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using the .Skip and .Take methods with Entity Framework.  The .Skip call is being honored when generating the SQL.  The .Take is not.  This code:

```
        public IList<DocPullRun> GetDocRunsPaginated(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows) {

        Logger.Debug("GetDocRunsPaginated: startRowIndex: {0}, maximumRows: {1}", startRowIndex, maximumRows);
        Debug.Assert(startRowIndex >= 0);
        IOrderedQueryable<DocPullRun> sortedPulls = 
            from run in DB.DocPullRuns
                 .Include("DocumentPullDefinition")
                 .Include("DocumentPullDefinition.Case")
                 .Include("DocumentPullDefinition.DocCategory")
                 .Include("DocumentPullDefinition.Repository")
                 .Include("DocumentPullDefinition.Repository.ConcordanceRepository")

             orderby run.PullStarted descending
             select run;

        IQueryable<DocPullRun> query = sortedPulls.Skip(startRowIndex);
        if (maximumRows > 0)
            query.Take(maximumRows);

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Results in this SQL shown below (note that in this call, startRowIndex is 0 and maximumRows is **10**).  The Where clause contains WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0 (which is the .Skip part), but I expected to see a **Select TOP 10** but instead simply see a Select.  The resulting list has more than 10 elements.  Note that I ran SQL Trace and see that the SQL is indeed deferred and not actually sent until the last line: query.ToList().  Is this some type of bug?

```
    SELECT 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[PullStarted] AS [PullStarted], 
[Project1].[PullEnded] AS [PullEnded], 
[Project1].[MatchedQuery] AS [MatchedQuery], 
[Project1].[NewDocs] AS [NewDocs], 
[Project1].[UpdatedDocs] AS [UpdatedDocs], 
[Project1].[DeletedDocs] AS [DeletedDocs], 
[Project1].[Errors] AS [Errors], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[Requestor] AS [Requestor], 
[Project1].[RequestTime] AS [RequestTime], 
[Project1].[Query] AS [Query], 
[Project1].[Enabled] AS [Enabled], 
[Project1].[LastPullTime] AS [LastPullTime], 
[Project1].[Case_ID] AS [Case_ID], 
[Project1].[Case_Name] AS [Case_Name], 
[Project1].[Client_ID] AS [Client_ID], 
[Project1].[Matter_ID] AS [Matter_ID], 
[Project1].[Is_Active] AS [Is_Active], 
[Project1].[Requires_Case_Specific_Permissions] AS [Requires_Case_Specific_Permissions], 
[Project1].[Last_Update] AS [Last_Update], 
[Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project1].[Category_ID] AS [Category_ID], 
[Project1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
[Project1].[DefaultGridLayout] AS [DefaultGridLayout], 
[Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
[Project1].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[OfficeAbbr] AS [OfficeAbbr], 
[Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
[Project1].[Repository_ID1] AS [Repository_ID1], 
[Project1].[ConcordanceDBId] AS [ConcordanceDBId], 
[Project1].[Repository_ID2] AS [Repository_ID2], 
[Project1].[RepositoryType_Id] AS [RepositoryType_Id]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], [Project1].[PullStarted] AS [PullStarted], [Project1].[PullEnded] AS [PullEnded], [Project1].[MatchedQuery] AS [MatchedQuery], [Project1].[NewDocs] AS [NewDocs], [Project1].[UpdatedDocs] AS [UpdatedDocs], [Project1].[DeletedDocs] AS [DeletedDocs], [Project1].[Errors] AS [Errors], [Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], [Project1].[Requestor] AS [Requestor], [Project1].[RequestTime] AS [RequestTime], [Project1].[Query] AS [Query], [Project1].[Enabled] AS [Enabled], [Project1].[LastPullTime] AS [LastPullTime], [Project1].[Case_ID] AS [Case_ID], [Project1].[Case_Name] AS [Case_Name], [Project1].[Client_ID] AS [Client_ID], [Project1].[Matter_ID] AS [Matter_ID], [Project1].[Is_Active] AS [Is_Active], [Project1].[Requires_Case_Specific_Permissions] AS [Requires_Case_Specific_Permissions], [Project1].[Last_Update] AS [Last_Update], [Project1].[Category_ID] AS [Category_ID], [Project1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], [Project1].[DefaultGridLayout] AS [DefaultGridLayout], [Project1].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID], [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], [Project1].[OfficeAbbr] AS [OfficeAbbr], [Project1].[Repository_ID1] AS [Repository_ID1], [Project1].[ConcordanceDBId] AS [ConcordanceDBId], [Project1].[Repository_ID2] AS [Repository_ID2], [Project1].[RepositoryType_Id] AS [RepositoryType_Id], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[PullStarted] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[PullStarted] AS [PullStarted], 
        [Extent1].[PullEnded] AS [PullEnded], 
        [Extent1].[MatchedQuery] AS [MatchedQuery], 
        [Extent1].[NewDocs] AS [NewDocs], 
        [Extent1].[UpdatedDocs] AS [UpdatedDocs], 
        [Extent1].[DeletedDocs] AS [DeletedDocs], 
        [Extent1].[Errors] AS [Errors], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent2].[Requestor] AS [Requestor], 
        [Extent2].[RequestTime] AS [RequestTime], 
        [Extent2].[Query] AS [Query], 
        [Extent2].[Enabled] AS [Enabled], 
        [Extent2].[LastPullTime] AS [LastPullTime], 
        [Extent3].[Case_ID] AS [Case_ID], 
        [Extent3].[Case_Name] AS [Case_Name], 
        [Extent3].[Client_ID] AS [Client_ID], 
        [Extent3].[Matter_ID] AS [Matter_ID], 
        [Extent3].[Is_Active] AS [Is_Active], 
        [Extent3].[Requires_Case_Specific_Permissions] AS [Requires_Case_Specific_Permissions], 
        [Extent3].[Last_Update] AS [Last_Update], 
        [Extent4].[Category_ID] AS [Category_ID], 
        [Extent4].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
        [Extent5].[DefaultGridLayout] AS [DefaultGridLayout], 
        [Extent6].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID], 
        [Extent6].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent6].[OfficeAbbr] AS [OfficeAbbr], 
        [Extent9].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID1], 
        [Extent9].[ConcordanceDBId] AS [ConcordanceDBId], 
        [Extent12].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID2], 
        [Extent13].[RepositoryType_Id] AS [RepositoryType_Id], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        1 AS [C2], 
        1 AS [C3], 
        1 AS [C4], 
        1 AS [C5]
        FROM           [dbo].[DocPullRuns] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocumentPullDefinitions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[DocumentPullDefinitionId] = [Extent2].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Cases] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CaseId] = [Extent3].[Case_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocCategories] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[CategoryId] = [Extent4].[Category_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocCategories] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[CategoryId] = [Extent5].[Category_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Repositories] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent2].[RepositoryId] = [Extent6].[Repository_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent7].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID3], [Extent7].[RepositoryType_Id] AS [RepositoryType_Id], [Extent7].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent7].[OfficeAbbr] AS [OfficeAbbr], [Extent8].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID4], [Extent8].[ConcordanceDBId] AS [ConcordanceDBId]
            FROM  [dbo].[Repositories] AS [Extent7]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ConcordanceRepositories] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[Repository_ID] = [Extent8].[Repository_ID] ) AS [Join6] ON [Extent2].[RepositoryId] = [Join6].[Repository_ID3]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ConcordanceRepositories] AS [Extent9] ON [Join6].[Repository_ID4] = [Extent9].[Repository_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent10].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID5], [Extent10].[RepositoryType_Id] AS [RepositoryType_Id], [Extent10].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent10].[OfficeAbbr] AS [OfficeAbbr], [Extent11].[Repository_ID] AS [Repository_ID6], [Extent11].[ConcordanceDBId] AS [ConcordanceDBId]
            FROM  [dbo].[Repositories] AS [Extent10]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ConcordanceRepositories] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[Repository_ID] = [Extent11].[Repository_ID] ) AS [Join9] ON [Extent2].[RepositoryId] = [Join9].[Repository_ID5]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ConcordanceRepositories] AS [Extent12] ON [Join9].[Repository_ID6] = [Extent12].[Repository_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Repositories] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent2].[RepositoryId] = [Extent13].[Repository_ID]
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[PullStarted] DESC
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

query.Take() doesn't mutate query; rather, it returns a *new* expression, which your code ignores. So change your code to:

```
if (maximumRows > 0)
    query = query.Take(maximumRows);
```

Comment: Arghh!  Rookie mistake!  Thanks Craig!

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for the if statement if you only ever want the maximum number of rows. If it does not reach the maximum then it will simply return whatever it gets.

You could just say:

```
  return query.Take(maximumRows).ToList();
```

Comment: This will only work if `maximumRows` is higher than 0. If `maximumRows` is 0, then no rows will be shown. But in his example he want to return all rows from the DB.